# How to make tab bar sticky at the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried **position: fixed**; in css but no luck. Notice when you scroll to the bottom, the tab will not be visible anymore. Is there a solution to make the tab bar sticky at the bottom of the page?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNG72910J1X0

Comment: Share your code what you have tried?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNG72910J1X0

Comment: Do you want like https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNG761DEDCTV ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position: absolute;` and change the `top: 100%;` to `bottom: 0;`.

```css
.social-icons {
  position: fixed;
  height: 90px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #46ce4f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 35px 30px -30px #777;
}

span {
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff0;
  line-height: 50px !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: snow;
  font-size: 25px !important;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

span:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

span:before {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

span:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #ea4335;
}

span:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #191919;
}

span:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #4867aa;
}

span:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #800080;
}

span:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: #00aced;
}

span:nth-of-type(6) {
  background: #ea4c89;
}

.after-span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.75s ease-in;
}

span:hover .after-span.ripple {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}

@media (max-width: 740px) {
  span {
    margin: 0 8px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .social-icons {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  span {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b01e280e04.js"></script>

<div class="social-icons">
  <span class="fa fa-google"><a class="after-span ripple"></a></span>
  <span class="fa fa-codepen"><a class="after-span ripple"></a></span>
  <span class="fa fa-facebook"><a class="after-span ripple"></a></span>
  <span class="fa fa-github"><a class="after-span ripple"></a></span>
  <span class="fa fa-twitter"><a class="after-span ripple"></a></span>
  <span class="fa fa-dribbble"><a class="after-span ripple"></a></span>
</div>
```

*Check it in action on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/GRNqRJX?editors=1100*